# IBM Watson Slots won't accept 0

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I'm trying out the slots feature in IBM Watson Conversations and have hit an issue which I'm not sure how to work around.

I have a use case that is collecting a number of pieces of information from a user so using the Slots feature makes sense. Unfortunately when I add a Slot with @sys-number the system will not accept 0 as a valid input. This slot is in fact required but 0 is a valid value.

Anyone have an idea of how to have a required Slot of type @sys-number that accepts 0 as a value?

Comment: Does the service recognize `0` as `@sys-number` when testing without slots? In my case it did.

Comment: Yes it does pick up on the `0` as `@sys-number` but doesn't appear to accept it as fulfilling the slot.

Comment: I think this question has already been answered. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43472182/ibm-watson-sys-number-does-not-get-0

Comment: That's different as it refers to leading zeros also it isn't related to the Slots feature. I did search before posting :)

Comment: It seems different because the linked answer is for preceding zeros. Here it is about slot-related flows. The zero seems to be detected as number, but the slot flow does not react accordingly.

Comment: I have asked it in the WDC slack, looks like a bug to me https://wdc-community.slack.com/archives/C0A23B42U/p1500988243670249 (if you don't have an account, join here http://wdc-slack-inviter.mybluemix.net/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The condition `@sys-number` is in fact a short hand syntax for condition `entities['sys-number'].value`. When `0` is sent the condition is evaluated to `false` as `0` is treated as a `false` by the expression language evaluator in Watson Conversation Service. Now this is not a desired behavior in this case. To prevent this for happening one can use `entities['sys-number']` in the condition that will return `true` every time `@sys-number` entity is recognized in the input.

When using this in slot one might want to edit what gets stored in the context variable as changing the condition will also change what is stored in the variable. This can be done by a JSON editor - click configure slot gear next to the slot specification and in the window that opens click three dots, open JSON editor and there change what gets actually stored inside the context variable that gets updated by the slot.

Here is a link to [system entity section in Watson Conversation Service documentation](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/system-entities.html#system-entity-detailshttp://).

Comment: Thanks Michal, confirmed as working with the slot condition as `entities['sys-number']` and the context variable set to `@sys-number` in the JSON editor for that slot.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem with recognising zero values in slots and the [system entity documentation](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/system-entities.html) did not explain it well enough (for me at least).

Further elaborating on Michal's answer above:

1. Click the "Edit Slot" option (gear icon)
2. Set the "Check For" attribute on a slot condition as `entities['sys-number']`

[image: edit slot modal]

3. Click the edit slot modal menu options (three bubbles in corner)
4. Open the JSON editor
5. Change the context variable value to `"<?entities['sys-number'].value ?>"`

[image: edit slot json editor]

---

Result:

[image: result]